# HQL custom On clause

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I would like to be able to model the following in in hql:

```
select
    people0_.NameFirst as col_1_0_,
    people0_.NameLast as col_2_0_,
    link1_.LinkValue as col_4_0_
from
    people people0_
left outer join
    peoplelinks peoplelink1_
        on (people0_.PersonID=link1_.PersonID and link1_.LinkTypeID=1)
;
```

This is part of a larger sql query and I just want to return all of the people whether or not they have a person with link type 1 associated with them. The person may have a link associated with them of a different type which is why I can not simply do

```
select
    people0_.NameFirst as col_1_0_,
    people0_.NameLast as col_2_0_,
    link1_.LinkValue as col_4_0_
from
    people people0_
left outer join
    peoplelinks peoplelink1_
        on people0_.PersonID=link1_.PersonID
 where
  link1_.LinkTypeID=1
;
```

Is there a way to write the first query in hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, hql has a with keyword. So this can be done the following way:

```
left outer join p.links l with l.linktypes.linkTypeId = :link_type_variable
```